# Написание слова "апокалипсис"

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Когда речь идет об апокалипсисе не как о главе Нового Завета, а как о конце света, глобальной катастрофе, это слово пишется с прописной или строчной буквы?
И, кстати, с какой буквы пишется сам "конец света"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По Лопатину - всё со строчной:

Апокалипсис, -а (часть Нового Завета) и апокалипсис, -а (конец света)

У меня нет повода для возражений.

Answer (score 3):

Слово АПОКАЛИПСИС имеет два значения. Первое - одна из книг Нового Завета, содержащая мистические пророчества о "конце света". Если слово употреблено в таком значении, его нужно писать с прописной буквы (имя собственное). Второе значение - конец света, гибель всего живого на Земле. В этом случае слово пишется со строчной.